# frappe-gantt not working in my angular 10 application

Tags: javascript, angular, frappe

I'm working on a project where the need is to show the tasks in gantt chart, I came across an open source library [frappe-gantt](https://frappe.io/gantt) and this fits for my use-case.

I tried implementing this in my angular application, I have installed this and added the `js` and `css` in `angular.json`

Then I followed the example given in official website, added `<svg>` to html file and `js script` to ts file of components.

```js
var tasks = [
  {
    id: 'Task 1',
    name: 'Redesign website',
    start: '2016-12-28',
    end: '2016-12-31',
    progress: 20,
    dependencies: 'Task 2, Task 3'
  },
]
var gantt = new Gantt("#gantt", tasks);
```

```html
<svg id="gantt"></svg>
```

This didn't work and showing blank only, then I added below to `index.html` in root

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/frappe-gantt/0.5.0/frappe-gantt.css" integrity="sha512-qxE5FnEACGZSuLsbaDLCYuMRrxuLhQz1HtOJ2+3dHXSnFlckToa1rXHajkgLciNSdq+FCE4ey8R8fqjrD3HO0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/frappe-gantt/0.5.0/frappe-gantt.min.js" integrity="sha512-5M8ejeX3DuiV4VGIFjHP5gpryPQb1dWYjzTUhBUKj81aT6ZZz6+wIG8k89nbjsiHFJHQbi/CByHQTe4mJOi3hw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and this to my component's `html` file

```html
<svg id="gantt"></svg>
<script>
var tasks = [
  {
    id: 'Task 1',
    name: 'Redesign website',
    start: '2016-12-28',
    end: '2016-12-31',
    progress: 20,
    dependencies: 'Task 2, Task 3'
  },
]
var gantt = new Gantt("#gantt", tasks);
</script>
```

but again not luck, however when I'm adding this to my root `index.html` it's working there. What is right way to use `frappe-gantt` in angular 10 application? So I can use in my components wherever I want.